# How to split a data frame into mutiple data frame based on row sequence

Tags: r

I want to ask how to split a data frame into multiple data frames by row sequence.
Here is my data. I got 1000 rows.

```
time  A  C  D  E
1.123 2  3  9  10
1.145 3  4  0  1
2     9  3  2  2
4     1  3  2  1
4.1   2  2  3  9
...
```

And I want to just split it by row's sequence, like this:
df[(1:100), ], df[(2:101), ], df[(3:102), ] ... df[(901:1000), ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lapply` :

```
list_output <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df) - 99), function(x) df[x:(x+99), ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is not very elegant, but if your dataset is not huge it gets the job done.

```
n <- 100
l <- list()
for (i in 1:(nrow(df) - n))
  l[[i]] <- df[i:(i+n-1),]
```